# Barrier does not work for Linux to WIndows connection

Tags: networking, server, vmware, synergy

Hello I have been trying for a while to connect my mouse and keyboard using barrier between Ubuntu and Windows.

1. I tried different way to connect. for example changing port, disable enable SSL, putting same device name and so on. But nothing is working.
2. I tried windows as a server and also tried Ubuntu as a server but could not connect.

In server's log it shows "`waiting for clients" \n "server status : active` "
In client's log it shows

```
[2022-05-20T00:51:46] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out
[2022-05-20T00:51:47] NOTE: connecting to '192.168.0.37': 192.168.0.37:24801
[2022-05-20T00:51:47] INFO: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
[2022-05-20T00:52:02] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out
```

My question is am I only one who is facing this issue? or It is not possible for Ubuntu and Windows to connect using barrier. If so, what free software or way (hardware) do you recommend me to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you disabled windows firewall or added rules to allow the two systems to talk right?  windows runs a restrictive inbound firewall out of the box

Comment: @ThomasWard I have been searching a solution for weeks man thank you so much for your help. I allowed firewall to allow barrier but it didn't work. It worked only when I totally disable all firewall options. also I disable ssl in barrier. Thanks a lot man. finally, its working smoth.

Comment: probably means there's more than one firewall rule you have to add to make sure Barrier works.  In either case, that's a Windows firewall problem not an Ubuntu problem.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Try this in your Ubuntu server:

```bash
sudo iptables -F
```

`-F` stands for `flush`, and so `--flush` option can also be used instead of `-F`.

### Full Explanation

I faced the same issue past few days and I tried all the things aforementioned in your question.

Additionally, I tested the working of Barrier version `2.3.4` and `2.4.0` releases in another set of machines which had `Ubuntu@22.04` as the server and `Win10` as client. It was working.

Then I searched for whether the firewall is not letting me through. I tested the inbound and outbound rules for `barrier` in Win10 machine, and also tested `localhost` port connection using `Test-NetConnection` command. Everything was fine at the `Win10`'s end.

I did the same kind of testing in my `Ubuntu@18.04` machine using the `nc` command. And it was giving me a positive response.

Trying to ping the other machine was still not working.

After doing all this, I added firewall rules in Ubuntu using `ufw`, and tried to check if my config is correct in `/etc/hosts`.

After doing everything, I remembered that there's a command to flush/reset all the network firewall rules and reset `tcp`/`udp` connections. And hence, I did that, and it worked like magic.

I also tried solutions posted in the official repo of barrier, but they didn't work.

In your server (I was using `Ubuntu@18.04`), try to reset the firewall rules in terminal using the following command:

```bash
sudo iptables -F
```

PS: Check your Windows machine's Inbound and Outbound rules for `barrier` application just in case. Use the following guide to read and understand how to tinker with firewall rules in Windows: https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/

PPS: These are the official troubleshooting steps given in `barrier`'s GitHub Repo: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Hi I have solved the problem already. I am going to add my the solution's steps in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

My devices: one laptop (Windows), one laptop (Ubuntu)

Steps:

1. Both device need to be connected with same internet/wifi
2. Disable all firewall on windows and create windows as your barrier server

   - Disable scroll lock.
   - Disable led light of keyboard if LED light uses scroll lock key to turn on.
3. There's no need to enable ssl.

Additional steps:
If you still face problems then try to

1. Change the port on barrier settings.
2. The server will provide 2 IPs to connect. Try the second one.
3. Sometimes multiple barrier apps keep running on the same device. For windows, check 'show hidden icon' from the taskbar and check if multiple barrier applications are running or not. Also check the other device. Try to close all barrier applications, then start again.

That's all. I hope everything will work now. I've been using it for months. I really like it.